# FTDI USB Chip in UART Mode and Bitbanging at same time

Tags: uart, gpio, ftdi

Using a FTDI FT2232D ([Datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232D.pdf)) in UART Mode for a dual RS-485 application I like to use some of the pins (e.g. not used handshake signals) as GPIOs (e.g. for switching on/of a termination resistor).

Does anybody know if this is supported in parallel to the VCP Driver for Linux? How would I access the pins separately?

Comment: You may have to roll your own driver

Answer (score 1):

The Bit bag modes only apply if NOT using the UART. All 8 lines are switched at the same time when changing the mode. You could use one if the 2 in bit bang and the other as UART. 
http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN232B-01_BitBang.pdf